# ssrs 2012 switch expression causing error

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012

=Switch(Fields!sale.Value = "1", Fields!REC_ISU.Value, "0", Fields!sale.Value = "2", Fields!REC_ISU.Value, "0", Fields!sale.Value = "3", Fields!REC_ISU.Value, "0")      This code is throwing error. Can anyone help. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

There are problems with the expression but without knowing what you expect this to do it's hard to give a complete answer.

The SWITCH expression works as follows...
For example if we wanted to look at a brand name and return whether it was a soft drink or alcohol we could do something like

```
=SWITCH(
        Fields!Brand.Value = "Coca-Cola", "Soft",
        Fields!Brand.Value = "Fosters", "Alcohol",            
        Fields!Brand.Value = "Smirnoff", "Alcohol",
        True, "Something else"
        )
```

This basically says "If the brand is Coca-Cola return "Soft", if it's Fosters or Smirnoff return "Alcohol", ELSE return "Something else". SWITCH stops evaluating when it finds a condition that is true, so the TRUE at the end acts like an else, it means none of the other tests are true.

We could make this shorter by replaceing

```
        Fields!Brand.Value = "Fosters", "Alcohol",            
        Fields!Brand.Value = "Smirnoff", "Alcohol",
```

with

```
    Fields!Brand.Value = "Fosters" OR Fields!Brand.Value = "Smirnoff", "Alcohol",
```

As you can see you can combine comparisons easily.

For more info look here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/report-design/expression-examples-report-builder-and-ssrs?view=sql-server-2017